# SQL writing today -1460 days?

Tags: sql

I have to change the code each day to make sure that is 4 years in the past based on list date. When I use '?' to set a parameter in excel it takes a long time to run. How can I hard code today -1460 days into this code? Below is current code.

```
Select 
MLB8.PROG_REPORT_ACCT_NUM_AND_PRACCT, 
DCGI.Date_Listed, 
DB.INITIAL_BALANCE, 
DS.Last_Payment, 
LV.Amt_Paid_On_Acct, 
DB.Principal_Balance, 
MLB7.INVENT_INVEN2
From
Clnt_General CG
Inner Join
Dbtr_Clnt_Generl_Inf DCGI on CG.Client_Num1=DCGI.Client
Inner Join
Dbtr_Status DS on DCGI.Account_Num1=DS.Account_Num1
Inner Join
Dbtr_Balances DB on DCGI.Account_Num1=DB.Account_Num1
Inner Join 
Debtor_Master_Logic_Blocks7 MLB7 on DCGI.Account_Num1=MLB7.Account_Num1
Inner Join 
Debtor_Master_Logic_Blocks8 MLB8 on DCGI.Account_Num1=MLB8.Account_Num1
Inner Join 
Letter_Variables LV on DCGI.Account_Num1=LV.Account_Num1
Where
CG.Client_Num1=?
And 
DCGI.Date_Listed>?
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS

Comment: If Oracle, you would use add_months( trunc(sysdate), -12*4 )

Comment: If MySQL DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 YEAR)

Comment: Don't forget about leap years.

Comment: In standard SQL: `current_date - interval '4' year`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the question ... because it seems very simple ...

```
DCGI.Date_Listed>= trunc(sysdate)-1460
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says SQLUSER.TRUNC does not exist when I use that.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know you are using sql server.
other (normal :) ) DB support what I wrote.

try:

```
DCGI.Date_Listed>=DATEADD(day, -1460, cast(getdate() As Date))
```